# Generic output schema with one variable difference

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-php

Quick question, im working with swagger-php to annotate my API. The output of the API always has the same basic structure and is being used over several endpoints:

```
[
  {
    "status": "success",
    "count": 0,
    "schema": "Hash.Hash",
    "items": [
      { ... },
      { ... },
      **LIST OF ITEMS IN THE schema Hash.Hash**
    ],
    "log": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
]
```

My solution for this is using an output model and reference that in the reposonse:

```
/**
* @OA\Schema(schema="OutputModel",
*          @OA\Property( property="status", default="success", type="string", format="string" ),
*          @OA\Property( property="count", default=0, type="integer", format="int32" ),
*          @OA\Property( property="schema", default="Hash.Hash", type="string", format="schema" ),
*          @OA\Property( property="items", type="array", @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Hash.Hash")),
*          @OA\Property( property="log", type="array", @OA\Items(type="string") ),
* )
*/

/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *  path="/api/v1/hash/",
 *  @OA\Response(response="200", description="List of added hashes",
 *      @OA\JsonContent(@OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/OutputTest")),
 *  )
 * )
 */
```

My challenge here is that in the output model, the property `items` is not always of schema Hash.Hash but different for every output. My current solution is to make a new output model for every endpoint and just change the ref="#/components/schemas/**Hash.Hash**" for the right schema, but this does not look very efficient. Is there a way to make this work using one generic OutputModel, different endpoints with different schemas?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading/tinkering i found the best solution for me:

replaced:

```
@OA\Property( 
  property="items", type="array", 
  @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Hash.Hash")
)
```

for:

```
      @OA\Property( property="items", description="TODO", type="array",
            @OA\Items(anyOf={
               @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/Hash.Hash"),
               @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/Show.ShowsFollow"),
               ...etc etc...
            }))
```

And replaced:

```
@OA\Property( property="schema", default="Hash.Hash", type="string", format="schema" ),
```

for:

```
@OA\Property( 
  property="schema", default="", 
  type="string", format="schema", 
  enum={"Hash.Hash", "Show.Showsfollow", ... etc,etc ...} 
)
```

This definition works for me because the `schema` string defines the object type and the `items` is filled with that object.

Ties.